# Contact Us Success Message Not Displaying Properly

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, contact-us, messages, page-content

I'm using the standard Contact Us page in Magento and it is not in a CMS page. When a customer sends a message, the success message does display. However, the page header is moved down and displays on top of the success message. I have looked everywhere and have no idea how to fix this. Feel free to send me a test message to see what I mean. Use the Contact Us link in the footer of www.shademountainarmory.com.

[image]

The only thing I could find in the Magento files relating to the success message was found in app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php. Here's the message code...

```
$translate->setTranslateInline(true);
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;
```

I can't find anywhere to modify WHERE the message appears since it seems to bump my page header down.

Comment: how did you add that success message ? Show relevant codes

Comment: Sure this isn't a CSS issue? Too many neophytes want to hack code for position and presentation.

Answer (score 2):

This is not due to magento's code. Please make changes in css.

- Open styles.css
- Add class

  .contacts-index-index .page-title
  {
  margin:0;
  }

Comment: That worked to a point. If you look at it now, it definitely fixed the location of the message. However, it took the header and made it smaller and placed it inside of the column instead of at the top of it.

Comment: If you inspect current css, you will find that this is due to padding:19px in .col-main.

Comment: I don't believe that's it. If you look at every other menu item, the page header sits on top of the white area (where it should be). Only in the Contact Us page does the header actually sit down in the white area. Changing the padding to 0px may expand the header to fit the width of the column on the Contact Us page, but it messes all of the other pages up. Unless I'm completely misunderstanding what you're suggesting?

Comment: OK, so I created a "Contact Us" CMS page and added the contact form to it successfully. I added a URL redirect so that, after submitting, the form redirected back to itself. However, I have the same problem as before. The page title (Contact Us" is being bumped down and is displaying on top of the success/error message, just as in the photo in the question.